# Andengine. Put bullet to pool, when it leaves screen

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

i'm creating a bullet with physics body. Bullet class (extends Sprite class) has `die()` method, which unregister physics connector, hide sprite and put it in pool

```
public void die() {
    Log.d("bulletDie", "See you in hell!");
    if (this.isVisible()) {
        this.setVisible(false);

        mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(physicsConnector);

        physicsConnector.setUpdatePosition(false);

        body.setActive(false);

        this.setIgnoreUpdate(true);

        bulletsPool.recyclePoolItem(this);
    }

}
```

in `onUpdate` method of PhysicsConnector i executes die method, when sprite leaves screen

```
physicsConnector = new PhysicsConnector(this,body,true,false)
    {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {

            super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

            if (!camera.isRectangularShapeVisible(_bullet)) {
                Log.d("bulletDie","Dead?");
                _bullet.die();
            }

        }
    };
```

it works as i expected, but `_bullet.die()` executes TWICE.
what i`m doing wrong and is it right way to hide sprites?

here is full code of Bullet class (it is inner class of class that represents player)

```
private class Bullet extends Sprite implements PhysicsConstants {
    private final Body body;

    private final PhysicsConnector physicsConnector;

    private final Bullet _bullet;

    private int id;

    public Bullet(float x, float y, ITextureRegion texture, VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager) {
        super(x,y,texture,vertexBufferObjectManager);

        _bullet = this;

        id = bulletId++;

        body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld, this, BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody, bulletFixture);

        physicsConnector = new PhysicsConnector(this,body,true,false)
        {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {

                super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

                if (!camera.isRectangularShapeVisible(_bullet)) {
                    Log.d("bulletDie","Dead?");
                    Log.d("bulletDie",id+"");
                    _bullet.die();
                }

            }
        };

        mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(physicsConnector);

        $this.getParent().attachChild(this);
    }

    public void reset() {

        final float angle = canon.getRotation();

        final float x = (float) ((Math.cos(MathUtils.degToRad(angle))*radius) + centerX) / PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;
        final float y = (float) ((Math.sin(MathUtils.degToRad(angle))*radius) + centerY) / PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setIgnoreUpdate(false);

        body.setActive(true);
        mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(physicsConnector);
        body.setTransform(new Vector2(x,y),0);

    }

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setLinearVelocity(Vector2 velocity) {
        body.setLinearVelocity(velocity);
    }

    public void die() {
        Log.d("bulletDie", "See you in hell!");
        if (this.isVisible()) {
            this.setVisible(false);

            mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(physicsConnector);

            physicsConnector.setUpdatePosition(false);

            body.setActive(false);

            this.setIgnoreUpdate(true);

            bulletsPool.recyclePoolItem(this);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

additional condition to check visibility of sprite prevented second executions of die method

```
physicsConnector = new PhysicsConnector(this,body,true,false)
{
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {

        super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

        if (!camera.isRectangularShapeVisible(_bullet) && _bullet.isVisible()) {
            Log.d("bulletDie","Dead?");
            _bullet.die();
        }

    }
};
```